# How can I locale-format a python Decimal and preserve its precision?

Tags: python, decimal

How can I format a `Decimal` using a locale?

To describe by examples, I'm trying to define a function `f` such that in the US English locale:

- `f(Decimal('5000.00')) == '5,000.00'`
- `f(Decimal('1234567.000000')) == '1,234,567.000000'`

Some things that don't work:

- `f = str` doesn't use locale; `f(Decimal('5000.00')) == '5000.00'`
- `f = lambda d: locale.format('%f', d)` doesn't preserve the decimal precision; `f(Decimal('5000.00')) == '5000.000000'`
- `f = lambda d: locale.format('%.2f', d)` uses a fixed precision, which isn't what I'm after; `f(Decimal('1234567.000000')) == '1234567.00'`

Comment: I assume you're aware that it's easy to get those thousands separators with e.g., `format(Decimal('1234567.8000'), '6,f')` -> `'1,234,567.8000'`.  The hard part is having that adapt to the current locale.

Comment: I found a library which purports to do this with its `format_decimal` method, but fails to maintain the full precision: http://babel.pocoo.org/docs/numbers/ If a satisfactory answer is reached, the contributor might consider submitting a pull request against that library to fix the issue.

Answer (score 12):

Reading through the source for the `decimal` module, `Decimal.__format__` provides full [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) support, and all you have to do is select the correct presentation type. In this case, you want the `:n` type. According PEP 3101 spec, this `:n` has the following properties:

> 'n' - Number. This is the same as 'g', except that it uses the
>                 current locale setting to insert the appropriate
>                 number separator characters.

This is simpler than other answers, and avoids the float precision issue in my original answer (preserved below):

```
>>> import locale
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> 
>>> def f(d):
...     return '{0:n}'.format(d)
... 
>>> 
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_us')
'en_us'
>>> print f(Decimal('5000.00'))
5,000.00
>>> print f(Decimal('1234567.000000'))
1,234,567.000000
>>> print f(Decimal('123456700000000.123'))
123,456,700,000,000.123
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'no_no')
'no_no'
>>> print f(Decimal('5000.00'))
5.000,00
>>> print f(Decimal('1234567.000000'))
1.234.567,000000
>>> print f(Decimal('123456700000000.123'))
123.456.700.000.000,123
```

### Original, wrong answer

You can just tell the format string to use as much precision as is included in the decimal itself and use the locale formatter:

```
def locale_format(d):
    return locale.format('%%0.%df' % (-d.as_tuple().exponent), d, grouping=True)
```

Note that works if you've got a decimal which corresponds to a real number, but doesn't work correctly if the decimal is `NaN` or `+Inf` or something like that. If those are possibilities in your input, you'd need to account for them in the format method.

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
'en_US'
>>> locale_format(Decimal('1234567.000000'))
'1,234,567.000000'
>>> locale_format(Decimal('5000.00'))
'5,000.00'
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'no_no')
'no_no'
>>> locale_format(Decimal('1234567.000000'))
'1.234.567,000000'
>>> locale_format(Decimal('5000.00'))
'5.000,00'
>>> locale_format(Decimal('NaN'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in locale_format
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'
```

Comment: This gives the wrong answer on both of the examples in the question.

Comment: Adding `grouping=True` generates the correct answer according to the examples in the question [edited answer to fix]. Unfortunately, that doesn't deal with the float precision issue that unutbu mentioned above.

Comment: @ChrisMartin: I added a solution that I think addresses all issues, using the :n presentation type.

Comment: Wow, fantastic :) You could also use `f = '{:n}'.format`.

Comment: it's enough to use: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US')`

Answer (score 12):

A modern Python approach with Python 3.5+ would be:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE")
>>> f'{Decimal("5000.00"):n}'
'5.000,00'
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "en_US")
'en_US'
>>> f'{Decimal("5000.00"):n}'
'5,000.00'
```

F-strings support advanced formatting. Hence, there is no need for extra `f` function. [Babel for Python](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/numbers.html) will give you a bit more convenience:

```
>>> from babel import numbers
>>> numbers.format_decimal(.2345, locale='en_US')
'0.234'
>>> numbers.format_decimal(.2345, locale='de_DE')
'0,234'
```

Comment: With Python 3.10, you need to set the locale with an encoding specifier (at least this is so on my system):
     locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "fr_FR.UTF-8")