# deformat locale number string back to number

Tags: python, locale, number-formatting

I can create a locale Number string via

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8')
numberstring = '{0:n}'.format(number)
```

(I found this on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31923117).)

Now, I have an input from the user. I don't know whether it is a valid locale number string or not. If it is, I want to convert it to a number. If it is not, I want to send an error and let him retry.

What is the best-practice solution i.e. the one that uses the functions from the `locale` lib that are meant for this? (I guess this does exist?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't [`locale.delocalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.delocalize) solve your problem? For example:

```py
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8')
numberstring = '{0:n}'.format(1700.5)   # "1 700,5"
normalized = locale.delocalize(numberstring)  # "1700.5"
try:
    number = float(normalized)  # 1700.5
except ValueError:
    # Not a number
```

Comment: The bad thing with this routine happens if you don't want to change your locale while need to convert number from another locale...  Does anyone know how to do the same without call locale.setlocale()?