# Creating python decimal with locale formatted string

Tags: python, decimal

I am using the Python decimal module, I’ve set my locale to Germany such that `locale.localeconv()["decimal_point"]` is `","`. When I try creating a decimal like `decimal.Decimal("1,23")`, I get a decimal conversion syntax error. When I do `decimal.Decimal("1.23")`, it works.

Does the Python decimal not respect locale settings when creating decimal from string?

Comment: subclass `Decimal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `decimal.Decimal` constructor only accepts numeric strings according to the [grammar shown](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal), where `.` is the only decimal point supported.

> ```
> decimal-part   ::=  digits '.' [digits] | ['.'] digits
> ```

The locale settings are only relevant for formatting a `Decimal` back to a string, see e.g. [How can I locale-format a python Decimal and preserve its precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910741/how-can-i-locale-format-a-python-decimal-and-preserve-its-precision)